# OJ says compile error about my python program even if it runs well on my computer (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

i wrote a simple python program for my homework that wants us to add up three integers given from input. i submitted it to my school's oj (online judge) system, but i got "compiler error"

the program runs very well on my personal computer that runs ubuntu 18.04 amd64, but i can't get it pass the oj test. i sincerely don't know what went wrong because the oj didn't give any message, only a final status "compiler error"

```
import sys

a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
c = int(c)
answer = a + b + c
print(f"The answer is {answer}")
```

here's the result when i run my program on my computer:

```
ubuntu@VMware:~/python-intro $ python3 1003.py
3
4
5
The answer is 12
```

and my computer system:

```
ubuntu@VMware:~/python-intro $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

how can it be a compiler error on the oj?? i have confirmed that my submission language is "python 3" not "python 2" or whatever.

Comment: Can you tell what version of python 3 is being used on the OJ?

Comment: i have no idea. they tell me nothing, but the oj system is somewhat old and aged

Comment: Just my guess. What if you don't use the f-string format?  just `print("The answer is {answer}")`.

Comment: it says wrong answer instead of compile error, but why would i print {answer} instead of the number?

Comment: I'm sorry it was lacking . `print("The answer is {answer}".format(answer=answer))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the python 3 version of your OJ is not python 3.6. And you can't use f-string on python versions below 3.6.

I suggest to change your string format to:

```
print("The answer is {answer}".format(answer=answer))
```

Answer (score 0):

f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. In an earlier Python, this line is a syntax error:

```
print(f"The answer is {answer}")
```

To ensure compatibility, rewrite it to

```
print("The answer is %s" % answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mostly related to f-string as Amadan pointed out.

print(f"The answer is {answer}") <<<

change this with format usage and update the thread.

print("The answer is {}".format(answer))